# Default argument allowing constructor to call private method

Tags: c++, constructor, private, most-vexing-parse

I have the class

```
class A
{
public:
    class Key
    {
        Key() {}
        Key(Key const &) {}
    };

    A(Key key, int a = 5) {}
};
```

The constructor for `Key` is private, so no one should be able to construct an object `A`. However, with the following code:

```
int main() {
    A a(A::Key()); // this compiles !!!
    A a2(A::Key(), 5); // this doesn't
    // somehow defaulting the argument causes the private constructor
    // to be OK - no idea why
    return 0;
}
```

By making use of the default argument for `int a` in my constructor, the compiler happily compiles my usage of `A::Key()` despite the fact that it is private. If I explicitly give a value for `a`, though, the compiler correctly recognizes that I am trying to use a private constructor and errors out. Why is this? Is there someway to force the compiler to error out for the first example as well?

See [here](https://ideone.com/fqeGGc) for live example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the most vexing parse.

```
A a(A::Key());
```

Does not create a `A` named `a` and construct it with a temporary `A::Key`.  It creates a function `a` that returns an `A` and takes an unnamed pointer to function that returns a `A::Key`.

If you add a pair of parentheses to it you will get a compiler error

```
A a((A::Key()));
```

That you are trying to call a private constructor.  Alternatively you can use uniformed initialization which also disambiguate it and will cause a compile error

```
A a(A::Key{});
```

Comment: I knew I'd seen this somewhere before... one of those things I run into once every 5 years and am flummoxed by because I haven't seen it in so long... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @R_Kapp No problem, glad to help.